# Retrieve values from Django Model and show in custom html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to retrieve values from my Model and display it in my template. I have custom HTML for CreateView and custom HTML for UpdateView.

I have multiple radio buttons in my custom HTML in my update view.

```
<div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">radio group1</label> 

           <input type="radio" value="No Issue" name="group1" id="id_lens_dirty_0">No Issue 

           <input type="radio" value="Non Critical" name="group1" id="id_lens_dirty_1"> Non Critical 

           <input type="radio" value="Critical" name="group1" id="id_lens_dirty_2" > Critical 
    </div>
 <div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">radio group</label> 

           <input type="radio" value="No Issue" name="group2" id="id_lens_dirty_0">No Issue 

           <input type="radio" value="Non Critical" name="group2" id="id_lens_dirty_1"> Non Critical 

           <input type="radio" value="Critical" name="group2" id="id_lens_dirty_2" > Critical 
    </div>
 <div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">radio group3</label> 

           <input type="radio" value="No Issue" name="group3" id="id_lens_dirty_0">No Issue 

           <input type="radio" value="Non Critical" name="group3" id="id_lens_dirty_1"> Non Critical 

           <input type="radio" value="Critical" name="group3" id="id_lens_dirty_2" > Critical 
    </div>
 <div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">radio group4</label> 

           <input type="radio" value="No Issue" name="group4" id="id_lens_dirty_0">No Issue 

           <input type="radio" value="Non Critical" name="group4" id="id_lens_dirty_1"> Non Critical 

           <input type="radio" value="Critical" name="group4" id="id_lens_dirty_2" > Critical 
    </div>
 <div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">radio group5</label> 

           <input type="radio" value="No Issue"  name="group5" id="id_lens_dirty_0">No Issue 

           <input type="radio" value="Non Critical" name="group5" id="id_lens_dirty_1"> Non Critical 

           <input type="radio" value="Critical" name="group5" id="id_lens_dirty_2" > Critical 
    </div>
```

Is there a way to get the values back and check appropriate radio button? I have about 50-60 radio button group in my update view, thus I do not want to use any kind of check method which will affect the performance.

View.py

```
class InsUpdateView(ReversionUpdateView):
    template_name = "ins/edit.html"
    model = Insp

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(InsUpdateView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return data
```

Comment: edit your question with your `views.py` added, this part of the code is important for any help

Comment: data you retrieve from your model, is it a Queryset? why you don't show all your codes. A possible approach is to send a list or query set to your templates, and check whether an item is inside that list, if yes, the status is checked/selected